# How to delete the SQLIte3 database tables and accessing database shell in windows cmd?

Tags: django, django-models, sqlite, django-rest-framework

I'm working on Django REST Framework tutorial and I've covered most of the tutorial. At the end I've encountered an `'Operational Error - no such column: snippets_snippet.owner_id'`. The tutorial tells to delete the database using following commnands:

```
rm -f tmp.db db.sqlite3
rm -r snippets/migrations
python manage.py makemigrations snippets
python manage.py migrate
```

&

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

but its not working. 
I'm working on windows-7 and it doesn't interpret first command. I've tried several other ones like - `'python manage.py sqlflush'`.

I'm working with only built-in SQLite who comes with django-1.8, How can I access SQLite dbshell? Is it necessary to install SQLite3 database manually rather than built-in one to access database utilities?

Please help me to Fix this issue....

Comment: The sqlite db is just a file. If you don't know how to delete it from the shell, just use Windows Explorer.

Comment: The tutorial is assuming you are working on a linux system.  Those rm  commands remove files.

Answer (score 0):

Download sqlite3 for Windows and then execute **sqlite3.exe** (double click on the "icon" is enough). Then you can open the database:

```
sqlite> .open example.db
```